# Is there a mathematical proof of the effectiveness of the target network trailing in Deep Q learning?

Tags: neural-network, reinforcement-learning, computation-theory, q-learning

It seems to be common practice in [Deep Q-learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-q-learning-tutorial-mindqn-2a4c855abffc) to have the target network trailing the main network, and syncing them every 100 or so steps, but I am not clear as to why that is.

The best explanations I have received as to why are ambiguous is:

> it prevents the net to chase its own tail

Is there a mathematical proof that it yields better results than having the target and main network be the same at all times?

Answer (score -2):

The use of a target network, like nearly everything in machine learning, was found emperically. It was created by the DeepMind team in their seminal 2013 paper:

> ### [Playing Atari with Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5602.pdf) <sup>[archive](https://ar5iv.labs.arxiv.org/html/1312.5602)</sup>

And it just became what everyone does; a de-facto standard.